# Git development cycle

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

I have an application which is under git revision. I have created a module for this application. Both repositories share the same file structure though the module repository only contains files that are particular to it's function. Both are local. For development purposes I need to test on a remote site. Up until now I have:

1) Cloned the application repository locally
2) Added the module repository as a remote and fetched

My ideal solution would:

1) Push the changes to the local repository (without having to merge)

Right now I am creating a local branch to replicate the module repository and trying rebase it on top of the master branch and am receiving errors about "cherry-picking" my commits.

Does anybody have any ideas on how I would achieve this?

Comment: A bit vague. Could you describe more clearly what you have done, especially on the local branch you create? What is module repository? What is replicate the module repository?

Comment: I created a clone of the remote instance. I then created a remote to connect to the module repository. They both have the same directories app code and local The module repository overwrites the files in the application repository thus updating it.

Comment: Wanted to re-phrase my question: